# why does Ubuntu on my hp pavilion laptop's battery is draining very fast?

Tags: 14.04, hp

i have install ubuntu 14.04 on my hp pavilion laptop 
initially when i was using windows 8.1 my battery use to be 2.30 hours to 3.00 hours 
but when i installed ubuntu 14.04 it started draining very fast and now its work for 1.30 hours only when my battery is fully charged ? what is the reason ?
and also my wifi signal strength has reduced from 5 point to 2 points? what might be the problem ? am i using incorrect drivers?
if so then please send me the link of the driver which i must used  ?

Comment: What is the video adapter?

Comment: For wi-fi have a look here:http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100590/why-does-linux-based-laptops-have-weak-wifi-signal-in-comparison-to-windows-base

Comment: @Pilot6 NVIDIA GeForce GT 840M

Comment: Did you install drivers for it?

Answer (score 0):

Power Management is not very efficient in Ubuntu by default. To get maximum performance, it is recommended to use third-party softwares. One of the best and highly configurable available software amongst them is TLP.

To install TLP, type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp
```

For more info visit the [TLP website](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html).